# Does imagemagick support image scaling algorithms related to depixelization

Tags: imagemagick

I am currently using this plugin for Paint.NET that provides a number of image filtering functionality. http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/23601-2d-image-scaling-algorithms/

I was looking at [this paper](http://johanneskopf.de/publications/pixelart/) and found it pretty interesting and was wondering if imagemagick supported those scaling algorithms.

For impact, here is a comparison between two results from the paper: [image]

I have a number of images that I would like to resize using this algorithm (or family of algorithms) and so it would be convenient to batch process it

Answer (score 1):

The results will not be as impressive as those from the paper but ImageMagick supports the Scale2x pixel art algorithm. With the -magnify (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#magnify) option that is only supported by mogrify you should be able to do this. Be aware of the fact that mogrify replaces the image you specify.

```
mogrify -magnify change-my-pixels.png
```